# Java Regular Expression pattern match

Tags: java, regex

I want to understand how the below Java regular expression program worked. I am not able understand the second line in the output of the program

```
String line = "This order was placed for QT3000! OK?";
      String pattern = "(.*)(\\d+)(.*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

  // Now create matcher object.
  Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
  if (m.find( )) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(1) );
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(2) );
```

This produces an output like this

```
Found value: This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
Found value: This order was placed for QT300
Found value: 0
```

I understand that the pattern we are searching for in the string is a sequence that is a number (`\d+`) with anything before `(.*)` and after it `(.*)`. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

I understood that m.group(0) returns the whole string. I didn't understand the second line of the output. **Found value: This order was placed for QT300**. What is happening here?

Answer (score 4):

It's returning the match produced from the first capturing group `( ... )`. And since `*` by default is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedy) operator, it's matching everything up until the last digit in the character string.

Breaking it down:

[image]

```
m.group(0)  →  Entire match     →  (.*)(\\d+)(.*) // This order was placed for QT3000! OK?
m.group(1)  →  Capture Group 1  →  (.*)           // This order was placed for QT300
m.group(2)  →  Capture Group 2  →  (\\d+)         // 0
m.group(3)  →  Capture Group 3  →  (.*)           // ! OK?
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to understand how this works with your explanation

Answer (score 1):

This is due to both greedy (as many as possible) and docile (give back when needed) from the regex. ([Greedy... but Docile](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedy))

- But if the quantified token has matched so many characters that the rest of the pattern can not match, the engine will **backtrack to the quantified token** and make it give up characters it matched earlier—one character or chunk at a time, depending on whether the quantifier applies to a single character or to a subpattern that can match chunks of several characters. After giving up each character or chunk, the engine tries once again to match the rest of the pattern. I call this behavior of greedy quantifiers docile.

Hence it pretty explains the situation u got there.

1. 0 Group : Match All
2. 1st Group : (.*) [Greedy] Match All but will backtrack to the following quantified token (\d+) `This order was placed for QT300`
3. 2nd Group : (\d+) [Greedy] At least one digit `0`
4. 3rd : (.*) [Greedy] `! OK?`

To understand better if you change the one to unlimited (\d+) to zero to unlimited (\d*), the Greedy behavior from Group 1 will take it all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was able to understand how this works with your explanation